# Arduino, max array size > 255?

Tags: c, arduino

I'm using [Arduino-IRremote](https://github.com/shirriff/Arduino-IRremote) code to read in an AC unit remote on an Arduino Uno R3.

There's a `unsigned int rawCodes[RAWBUF]`. When I set `RAWBUF` to 255 it all works great. I push it to 256 and it uploads just fine, but there's no response.

Is this a memory limitation? [According to this](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/CorruptArrayVariablesAndMemory#Max_size_of_array), it's not. I should be able to get ~400 elements.

Also, because the limit I'm hitting is 255 makes me believe there's something else going on.

Thanks, Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have that limitation.

You're playing with high amounts of memory. Are you sure you have enough available memory to do so?
Looks like you're talking about runtime errors(of the memory leak/segfault type) here.

You can check [total available](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvailableMemory) memory or check [this great article (and code)](http://andybrown.me.uk/wk/2011/01/01/debugging-avr-dynamic-memory-allocation/) on how to debug AVR.

Also if you're using heavy static strings allocation, you can reduce memory usage by using [PROGMEM](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM) storage (and having impact on the available size for the sketch).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, the memory is just fine as we suspected. I ran across this posted 4 days ago: https://github.com/shirriff/Arduino-IRremote/issues/49. My exact issue. Time to dive deep into the code.

Comment: You're welcome! Just trying to help. Good job and happy hacking :-)

Answer (score 0):

Found that the variable controlling the buffer size was a uint8_t, so it was a simple change to 16 and now we've got the length I was looking for.

https://github.com/shirriff/Arduino-IRremote/issues/49